# Add a Stroke / Outline to a Custom Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a custom scrollbar that I would like to add a stroke/outline to. I have not found any articles on how to do this and the 'stroke' nor the 'outline' using CSS seems to do the trick. Is this possible to do?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hd2u4gs3/

```
<div id="box"></div>

body {
    background: black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 25px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #7e7e7e;
    stroke: yellow;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    height: 80px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}

#box {
    height: 10000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i was not wrong you need outline around thumb of scroll bar please
>   check the solution below

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 23px;
  background: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  
  background: red;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #7e7e7e;
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}

#box {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: @JohnSmith Glad to hear that! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding a right border to the box?

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 25px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: black;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #7e7e7e;
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  height: 80px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}

#box {
  height: 10000px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
    <div id="box"></div>
```

Or just add a `border-left` to the track: https://jsfiddle.net/owuc4jdf/

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: black;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I really need an outline on the thumb itself :(